# In C++, can the caller of a function ensure its arguments won't be modified?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

In the following C++ code:

```
int foo(int &x); /* a function prototype */

main()
{
    int i=5;
    foo(i);
}
```

Suppose I'm unable to change *foo()* in any way.

Is there a way, in *main()*, to call *foo()* so that it can't modify *i*?

Comment: AFAIK: No. You would always have to change foo to take a const param.

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking exactly, but I think what you need is const.

Comment: Usually, the point of taking a parameter by reference is to change it.  Either the function isn't designed well, or, by working around this, you will loose some of the service the function provides.

Comment: The other reason to take by reference is if the structure is large, but then it usually add const to give the intended use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give it a copy of `i`. That is the only way.

```
int j = i;
foo(j);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to prevent it, you can cast it to a const reference first:

```
template<class T> const T& const_(T& r) { return r; }
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    foo(const_(i));
}
```

But really: if you're not alllowed to modify it, why isn't it const already?

Comment: nice idea but it would not compile. A const int& won't bind to an int& parameter.